# From DataTable to BindingList

Tags: c#, inheritance, datagrid, bindinglist

I am  in the process of switching over from DataTable to BindingList. I bind the DataTable to the DataGrid object.

Here my dilemma: while I certainly see the advantages of switching over, my circumstances will make it a bit complex and I am wondering whether it is worth it to switch over.

My scenario:
I have a DataGrid which displays chemical samples. There are 5 kinds of sample type, where the columns in the grid will differ for each type (and sometimes within the same type based on other parameters). Some columns remain the same, some are present in 3 types, some in 4 etc etc. Not exactly a case of simple inheritance. Currently, I have a DataTable which makes it easy since I can load whichever columns I want without having to have properties for each sample type which is what I will have to do if I use BindingList. But then, BindingList will make it much easier down the road to refer to sample properties.

This is my first experience with this object (BindingList) so any suggestions welcome. From what I know BindingList binds to properties. So if I have:

```
public class Sample
{
    protected string m_seq;
    protected string m_id;
    protected string m_weight;
    protected string m_units;

    public Sample()
    {
    }

    public string Seq
    {
        get { return m_seq; }
        set { m_seq = value; }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return m_id; }
        set { m_id = value; }
    }

    public string Weight
    {
        get { return m_weight; }
        set { m_weight = value; }
    }

    public string Units
    {
        get { return m_units; }
        set { m_units = value; }
    }

} //end of class
```

The grid will be bound to the properties of Sample class if I have something like

```
BindingList samples = new BindingList<Sample>();
```

Which means I am going to have 6 types of samples, all with properties defined. The final inheritance structure may be complex, so I am wondering whether it is worth it at all. Any feedback is welcome.

I am using c# 2.0; it is a Windows App.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `DataGrid`, is there any chance you could switch to `DataGridView`? It will be far more flexible...

I'm not entirely sure from the question, but:

### If the properties are fixed, but you don't want to display all the columns

Then simply set `AutoGenerateColumns = false` before you add the data, and add the desired columns yourself; or alternatively, leave it enabled and simply set `.Visible = false` on the columns you don't want to see.

### If the properties are dynamic at runtime

Then it gets tricky; you're getting into the darker corners of `System.ComponentModel`; you can do this with `DataGridView` via `ITypedList` (which allows different definitions per list instance) or `TypeDescriptionProvider` (which allows different definitions per type or per list instance) - but of those, only `TypeDescriptionProvider` will work with `BindingList<T>`. To be honest, I don't think this is what you mean; and if it is, it would be simpler to stick with `DataTable` (both are very hard to implement correctly).

---

I hope that helps; and I hope it is as simple as hiding some columns! If I've missed the point, let me know.

Comment: I am using Compact Framework (I should've mentioned this but didn't want to get distracted from the question).

My question has to do more with design than with which particular control to use. I am limited to DataGrid.